# Google OAuth2 Issue - Error 400: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am making a bidding web application for which I am using Google OAuth2 Authentication in SpringBoot Maven. I have registered the same uri in Google Cloud Console, but still, I am getting Error 400 for redirect_uri_mismatch.
Google says this while logging in:
`You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy.

If you're the app developer, register the redirect URI in the Google Cloud Console.
Request details: redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/google
`
Application.properties file:

```
spring.security.oauth2..client.registration.google.client-id=792979004767-5fvs24lfomcue1h532sqdluskt60ieql.apps.googleusercontent.com
spring.security.oauth2..client.registration.google.client-secret={Client_Secret}
```

I tried adding logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE to minimise the security constraints, but still not able to get it running. I have tried it for multiple times, and have even tried all the previous solution written on Stackoverflow. Therefore, any help would be highly appreciated as I am a beginner in the field.